# How to copy data from one column row to the same column but different row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a DB in sql were I want to copy values of a column to the same column but different row. I have searched the internet and tried many things but I cannot get it to work...

I have added a picture of the data in green I want to copy, and showed in purple that the 4 rows below together that define a product or stock item ID.

https://snipboard.io/B4lEGx.jpg

Comment: first post your data in text format.

Comment: not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I guess you can use a statement based on SELECT INTO

Comment: appears SELECT INTO is not supported in mysql. here is link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html ... hope that helps. you can use INSET INTO and  SELECT WHERE  nested

Answer (score 0):

Below queries work only if stock_id exact matches wi_id 
Below query to view data

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON stock_id = wi_id
WHERE wi_id IN (14356, 527399, 56873, 581818);
```

Below query to update records

```
UPDATE TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON stock_id = wi_id
SET 
TABLE1.ColumnName1 = TABLE2.wi_warning_stock_level,
TABLE1.ColumnName2 = TABLE2.wi_ideal_stock_level
WHERE wi_id IN (14356, 527399, 56873, 581818);
```